# Convert hard drive to ntfs?

Tags: filesystem

As I installed Ubuntu 12.04 my hard drive changed file system from ntfs to ext4. How can I change it back to ntfs?

I don't have to save any files on my computer all I need is to change the file system.

Comment: Ubuntu must be installed to a ext4 filesystem.you can't change it to NTFS.if you does then forget Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you mean the partition that Ubuntu is installed on? To the best of my knowledge this can't be done - Ubuntu doesn't support NTFS as a file system (you can *mount* NTFS partitions, but by the sound of your question this seems to be more about the OS partition, correct?)

Comment: Yes, are you trying to get rid of Ubuntu?

Comment: I want to dual boot, windows and ubuntu

Comment: Then the question does not make sense: you would lose Ubuntu doing this.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would work with both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: @user-3.14159265359 After seeing your comments above, I have updated my answer below.

Comment: You need to show us your current partitioning layer so following instructions you won't mess up.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep Ubuntu and Windows in a dual boot then this isn't really possible. Ubuntu wasn't made to be installed on a NTFS system. Although you *can* do this it doesn't work well, and you can't switch EXT4 to NTFS without losing any existing installations of Ubuntu.

If you want to erase any existing installations, then continue on through this answer.

---

Boot some liveMedia. Select "Try Ubuntu".

Open the "Disks" app.

[image]

Select the hard drive and partition you want to format.

[image]

Click the little cog button, then select "format".

[image]

Use a "slow" format and choose "NTFS" as the format type. Give this partition a name.

[image]

Click "Format".

Comment: You can't do it within Ubuntu if that is the partition that Ubuntu is installed to.

Comment: @psusi Updated my answer.

Comment: OP wants to keep a dual boot and so may have to resize the existing partition then create a new NTFS drive.

Comment: @minerz029 I see that now. I was assuming he knew it would delete Ubuntu.